# Applications of $Ext^n$ in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, abelian-categories

I have been doing a project about $\operatorname{Ext}^n$ functors for my commutative algebra class. I used the approach via extensions of degree n. Basically I have shown the long exact sequence associated to a short exact sequence for $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is an abelian category.

To apply this construction I have proven the Chinese remainder theorem as a "toy" example. I would like to find applications in algebraic geometry that are not very technical. I feel confident with the language of sheaves but my general knowledge of algebraic geometry is very poor.

Could someone please point to some references where I can look?

Comment: What about the Serre duality theorem?

Comment: Let $X$ be a scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ a coherent sheaf. Then $\text{Ext}^{1}(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F})$ is the space of deformations of $\mathcal{F}$ (see theorem 2.6 here math.berkeley.edu/~robin/math274root.pdf). One also has, the isomorphisms $\text{H}^{i}(X,\mathcal{{Hom}}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F})) = \text{Ext}^{i}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F})$, for $i = 0,1$. If $X$ is projective, these cohomology groups (of coherent sheaves) are finite dimensional k-vector spaces by virtue of Serre's theorem.