# About alternative ways of computing $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(m))$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

This is a follow up to my question : [Applications of $Ext^n$ in algebraic geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784232/applications-of-extn-in-algebraic-geometry)

In the case of $\mathcal{O}_X$-Modules it is clear that $Ext^i(\mathcal{O}_X, \mathcal{F}) \cong H^i(X,\mathcal{F})$ so I was wondering if there is any particular case where you can compute $H^1(X,\mathcal{F})$ using the formalism of extensions of degree 1.

I am specially interested in the case $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(m)$ since I want to prove M.Noether's $AF+BG$ theorem.

Comment: I suppose that you know these are zero for $n>1$ and all $m$. For $n=1$, they are zero if $m\geq -1$. Are you asking for a way to calculate these without the usual formalisms?

Comment: Yes, I would like to show these facts without using Cech cohomology.

Comment: This can be done if you are willing to use enough commutative algebra-facts about depth, Auslander-Buchsbaum theorem.

Comment: Maybe if we set $n=2$ is it possible to find something easier?

Comment: Anyway could you outline how to use the argument you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an argument for $n=2$, the general case is not different. I will just write $\mathcal{O}$ instead of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}$. Let $0\to\mathcal{O}(m)\to E\to\mathcal{O}\to 0$ be an extension. Let $S=\oplus_k\mathrm{H}^0(\mathcal{O}(k))$ be the homogeneous coordinate ring. Applying this to our exact sequence, we get, $0\to S\to M\to S$, an exact sequence of graded $S$-modules, where $M=\oplus_k\mathrm{H}^0(E(k))$. The cokernel of $M\to S$ is supported only at the irrelevant maximal ideal and so, if not zero, we see that the image $I$ has depth exactly one and we have an exact sequence $0\to S\to M\to I\to 0$. Since $M$ has depth at least two, this implies depth of $S$ is two, which is false (this is where we use $n>1$). Thus, we see that $M\to S$ is onto and thus $M=S\oplus S$, which implies $E=\mathcal{O}(a)\oplus\mathcal{O}(b)$ and then it is immediate that $a=0, b=m$ and the sequence splits.

Comment: I am still digesting this but this is just what I needed. Maybe I will ask you some little questions.  Anyway, thaanks a lot!

Comment: "we see that the image $I$ has depth exactly one". How do you find this? Are you computing the depth with respect to the irrelevant ideal right?

Comment: $S/I$ ($I$ is the image of $M$), if not zero, is supported only at the irrelevant maximal ideal and thus depth zero. Since depth of $S>0$ (actually 3), it follows that depth of $I$ is one. Yes, computations of depth are made with respect to the irrelevant maximal ideal.

Comment: Dear @Mohan, I don't want to bother you, but due to my lack of experience using these techniques of commutative algebra I still find some parts of you proof hard to follow. Everything is clear except the depths computations and how this implies depth$(S)=2$. Could you make your answer a little bit more explicit? Maybe the inequalities you are using or when you use  Auslander-Buchsbaum theorem etc. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a general fact. Let $0\to K\to L\to M\to 0$ be an exact sequence of finitely generated graded modules over $S$ (all non-zero) and assume $\mathrm{depth}\, L>\mathrm{depth}\, M$. Then $\mathrm{depth}\, K=\mathrm{depth}\, M+1$.